# settings on a PERC H310 crossflashed to 9211-8i/IR

Tags: dell-perc, megaraid, raid-controller

I'm using MegaRAID Storage Manager on Windows Server 2012 R2 and am trying to change some settings on the card.  Sadly, the settings are missing entirely from the menu when I right-click on the controller.  Consistency check rate, bgi rate, rebuild rate, etc. are all missing their menu options.  Please see this image for what I am currently getting:

[image: First screenshot]

And this image (found on the web) for more along the lines of what I'm expecting to see:

[image: Second image]

As you can see, the options simply don't exist.  **Does anyone know what is going on, and if so, can you make any suggestions on how to make those options available?** Controller firmware and BIOS are at latest versions from Avago.  The server is an HP ProLiant DL380 G5.  (**Yes, I know it's a Dell controller on an HP server.**)

I can provide additional information as required. Thanks.

Comment: You're on the wrong tab!

Comment: @MichaelHampton unfortunately, no.  Same menu options appear when i right-click on the controller in the Logical tab